# dynamic text won't disappear

Tags: flash, loader

My preloader won't disappear, i have any other graphic inside the progMC it will disappear but  text stays there  "Loading:100%"

```
function loadProgress(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var percentLoaded:Number = event.bytesLoaded/event.bytesTotal;
    percentLoaded = Math.round(percentLoaded * 100);
    progMC.prog.text = "Loading:"+String(percentLoaded)+"%";
    //trace("Loading: "+percentLoaded+"%");
}
function loadComplete(event:Event):void
{

    var fade_out:Tween = new Tween(progMC, "alpha", Strong.easeOut, 1,0,0.3, true);

    //trace("Complete");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to embed your fonts

if your using the flash IDE it's simple
just click on your textField in progMC and click on embed...
make sure you select all the character sets you want to embed, and that should make your text fade away perfectly